# Programmatically create glossy 3d button

Tags: android

I have googled it already but can't find a good hint on how to create buttons in android that look like glossy shiny buttons with a slight 3d effect. See pic:

[image]

How can I programmatically do this?

Comment: Shadow effect: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShadowLayer(float, float, float, int)

Comment: one more idea to just display button like 3d is cut the particular button and set it to background, remove android:text="" from button layout.

Comment: The only solution I know for such complex effect is to use 9 patch png files.

Answer (score 3):

Create a selector like this and apply it to your button drawable. Customize it to your requirements:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>        
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#0905FB"
                    android:startColor="#9796FD"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="#65655B" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="3dp" />
                <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_focused="true" >
           ...
           ...
           ...
        </item>

       <item android:state_pressed="true" >
         ...
         ...
         ...
       </item>
   </selector>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, that will only give me the gradient look and the stroke, but it doesn't provide the 3d-look (the shiny bar on top of the button).