# Glossy button xml design in android

Tags: android, xml, button, gradient

I'm new to Android and I'm working on an app. I want my UI to be rich and I'm trying to make my Buttons look glossy.

I can't find solution yet. I trying to make my button something like this, please help me with this.
[Sample image link](http://cdn2.aquul.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Modern-Glossy-Button.jpg)

Comment: Try these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647919/programmically-create-glossy-3d-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049876/custom-button-glass-effect

Comment: Thank you Asha Soman, this links kinda useful